# How to turn imparfait into infinitif when the imparfait denotes a duration terminated by passé simple

Tags: infinitif, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

The question is on this sentence from chapter 6 of La porte étroite by André Gide.

> Miss Ashburton, dont la santé depuis quelques mois **déclinait**, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.

Dorothy Bussy's translation runs:

> Miss Ashburton, whose health **had been declining** for some months past, died four days before Christmas.

**QUESTION**

1. Suppose I wanted to change the sentence to:

   > Miss Ashburton, who **had been** ill for some months past, died four days before Christmas.

   Would French for that be:

   > (1A) Miss Ashburton, qui **était** malade depuis quelques mois, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.
2. Suppose I wanted to change the sentence to:

   > Miss Ashburton, **after being ill** for some months past, died four days before Christmas.

   Which of the following would be correct French for that:

   > (2A) Miss Ashburton, après **être** malade depuis quelques mois, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.
   >   (2B) Miss Ashburton, après **avoir été** malade depuis quelques mois, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.
3. Suppose we dropped the *depuis* phrase.  Would that change the answer?  I.e. which of the following would be correct?

   > (3A) Miss Ashburton, après **être** malade, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.
   >   (3B) Miss Ashburton, après **avoir été** malade, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.
4. If we were saying the same thing as 2 but in the present, which of the following would be correct:

   > (4A) Miss Ashburton, après **être** malade depuis quelques mois, meurt quatre jours avant Noël.
   >   (4B) Miss Ashburton, après **avoir été** malade depuis quelques mois, meurt quatre jours avant Noël.
5. If we were saying the same thing as 3 but in the present, which of the following would be correct:

   > (5A) Miss Ashburton, après **être** malade, meurt quatre jours avant Noël.
   >   (5B) Miss Ashburton, après **avoir été** malade, meurt quatre jours avant Noël.

Please make sure to give a definite answer to each of the five questions if you don't explain anything.  Thank you.

**BACKGROUND**

This background is not part of the question.  You don't have to read it.

What is motivating my question is noting that, though the period of decline would certainly have preceded (and terminated with) death, French does not make that sequence explicit the way English does with its *had been*.

The difference may be related to that in:

> - Je **suis** ici depuis deux jours.
> - I **have been** here two days.

and

> - j’y **étais** depuis deux jours quand je le rencontrai.
> - I **had been** there two days when I met him.

If I may say that *déclinait* and *mourut* (or *étais* and *rencontrai*) are "even" I am wondering whether that "evenness" is preserved when the imperfect is changed into a gerund phrase or French would now put the former imperfect "before" the simple past using an *avoir* form.

I note that French uses the *avoir* form even where English does not have to.

> Alissa t’attend dans le jardin, me dit mon oncle, après m’**avoir embrassé** paternellement lorsque, à la fin d’avril, j’arrivai à Fongueusemare.

It so happens that Dorothy Bussy here matches the French structure:

> "Alissa is waiting for you in the garden," said my uncle, after having embraced me paternally, when one day at the end of April I arrived at Fongueusemare.

In my view, however, "after embracing me" would have done too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is:

```
(1A):correct

(2A): incorrect
(2B): correct
```

3.Suppose we dropped the depuis phrase. Would that change the answer? I.e. which of the following would be correct?

```
(3A) incorrect
(3B) correct
```

*"depuis"* in french is a time adverb "adverbe de temps", it can be easily shifting or/and it can be removed.

4.If we were saying the same thing as 2 but in the present, which of the following would be correct:

```
(4A) incorrect
(4B) correct
```

5.If we were saying the same thing as 3 but in the present, which of the following would be correct:

```
(5A) incorrect
(5B) correct
```

The correct proposition (5B) is not in the present "au présent". It is *"au participe passé"*.

The simplest way to write this sentence with the verb *"meurt"* in the present is:

```
(5B) Miss Ashburton malade, meurt quatre jours avant Noël.
```

replace the proposition: *"après avoir été malade"* by *l'adjectif:* *"malade"*

Comment: Sans appel - I agree with with @sapienz, and it's pretty clear cut :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sapienz's answer, I don't think I need to write them again. I'll try to explain it a little more.

You sentence looks more or less like this:

> [subject], after [action1], does/did [action2]

If the verb for *action2* is anything but future tense, *action1* is **always** resolved, so can't have present tense for *action1* if you also have present tense (or past tense!) for *action2*.

Like you noted it your background, it has to do with the fact that there are two actions, one anterior to the other, so you have to show that.