# Expanding Infinitif passé to imparfait or plus-que-parfait

Tags: infinitif, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

The question is on this sentence from chapter 7 of La porte étroite by André Gide.

> (P) Alissa t’attend dans le jardin, me dit mon oncle, après m’**avoir embrassé** paternellement lorsque, à la fin d’avril, j’arrivai à Fongueusemare.

**QUESTION**

Which is the correct to way expand the gerund phrase to a *que* clause?

> (X) Alissa t’attend dans le jardin, me dit mon oncle, après qu'il m'**embrassa** paternellement lorsque, à la fin d’avril, j’arrivai à Fongueusemare.
>   (Y) Alissa t’attend dans le jardin, me dit mon oncle, après qu'il m'**avait embrassé** paternellement lorsque, à la fin d’avril, j’arrivai à Fongueusemare.

If neither please tell me the correct answer.

**BACKGROUND**

This background is not part of the question.  You don't have to read it.

I am expecting that the answer will be (Y).

What is motivating this question is the interesting contrast between the transformation of (P) to (Y), if that be the answer, and the transformation of

> (2B) Miss Ashburton, après **avoir été** malade depuis quelques mois, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.

to

> (1A) Miss Ashburton, qui **était** malade depuis quelques mois, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.

See [this other question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24352/how-to-turn-imparfait-into-infinitif-when-the-imparfait-denotes-a-duration-termi) in which I learned that (1A) and (2B) go together.

I try to explain the difference to myself this way: *était* marks out a period that preceded (and terminated with) the event of *mourut* while *avoir embrassé* is an event that preceded another event.  So when expanding an infinitif passé to a clause, one has to mind the grammatical aspect, the distinction of which is *lost* in an infinitif form.

Comment: Why do you want to change après m''avoir embrasé to après que? The first is considered more elegant.

Comment: @Lambie. I am trying to work out certain grammatical relationships. Yes, I realize that I may be injuring the elegance of the original text.

Comment: Ok, so this is only writing. I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both (X) and (Y) sound very odd.

What most people will probably use is the subjunctive present :

> *Alissa t’attend dans le jardin, me dit mon oncle, **après qu'il m'ait embrassé** paternellement lorsque, à la fin d’avril, j’arrivai à Fongueusemare.*

However, grammar rules states the indicative is required after *après que* so this is the best formal way:

> *Alissa t’attend dans le jardin, me dit mon oncle, **après qu'il m'eut embrassé** paternellement lorsque, à la fin d’avril, j’arrivai à Fongueusemare.*

Comment: Oh, thank you. I would like nothing better than *eut embrassé*. I only used  *avait embrassé* in the example because of the warning (in Web sites) that the passé antérieur was literary, that one should use the plus-que-parfait, etc.

Comment: And quite forgetting I was lifting things from Gide.