# How to turn "Je suis à Paris depuis deux" into an infinitive

Tags: infinitif, concordance-des-temps

Suppose someone says:

> - I have been in Paris (for) two days when I meet Tom; or
> - I have been working on the project for two years when I find the solution.

It might be voice-over narration in a movie using what is called the historical present.

For example:  A dreamy voice at the start of a movie, belonging to a character who is in a coma, to whom everything is the present. He recounts to you the events leading to his accident, starting: "I have been in Paris two days when I meet Tom. At first I don't recognize him.  He is with a woman. . ."; or "I have been working on the project for two years when I find the solution.  Everyone is there in the lab to congratulate me. No one notices the [warning signs]. . ."

**QUESTION**

1. Would this be the correct French for the historical present form of narration:

   > - Je suis à Paris depuis deux jours lorsque je rencontre Tom.
   > - Je travaille sur le projet depuis deux ans lorsque je trouve la solution.
2. If I then wanted to turn it around to say, "I meet him after being two days in Paris," or "After working on the project for two years I find the solution" (still in the historical present), should I say:

   > - Après avoir été à Paris depuis deux jours, je rencontre Tom.
   > - Après avoir travaillé sur le projet depuis deux ans, je trouve la solution.

Please note that I am *not* asking for the best way to say these things.  I am trying to resolve a grammatical issue for my owning understanding.  I need a sentence that embeds an infinitive about a preceding time period into a main clause in historical present.  Thank you.

**BACKGROUND**

I also asked [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24352/how-to-turn-imparfait-into-infinitif-when-the-imparfait-denotes-a-duration-termi) and [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24358/expanding-infinitif-pass%C3%A9-to-imparfait-or-plus-que-parfait) related question.

---

**AFTER READING THE ANSWERS AND COMMENTS**

This question is part of my trying to understand why one has to say:

> Je suis ici depuis deux jours

to mean

> I have been here (for) two days.

(Native French speakers may not see just how mystifying that is.)

Today I seem to have learned that they don't exactly mean the same thing.

*Je suis ici depuis deux jours* means, it would appear,

> I *am* here, and this my-being-here *is* two days old so far, and I say nothing about when it might end.

In other words, the same *suis* that began two days ago is still on-going.

But *I have been here two days* means

> I have completed a two-day segment of being here.

The segment ended.  Yes, I may still be here on a new segment of time that met end-to-end with the old, but that's not what I'm talking about.  I am talking about the old one that already ended.

It seems this critical difference is what makes Teleporting Goat not like

> Je travaille sur le projet depuis deux ans lorsque je trouve la solution

because a solution naturally suggests the end of the project, but *travaille* suggests the same work as still on-going.

Comment: Are you sure your English sentence is correct?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps. I tried to respond to your thought with an edit to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand you first sentence in English, I didn't know that form, I would have written "for two days" and would have used "met". This being said, your first French sentence is totally correct if you want someone talking in present tense about something that happened in the past because he wants to tell his story.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps. And the second French sentence? Is it correct too, ignoring whether it sounds good or bad?

Comment: I don't know if it's correct or not, but what sounds strange is that "avoir été" sounds like you are not in Paris anymore, but "depuis" means you still are. *"Après avoir été malade pendant deux jours, je me sens mieux"* is correct but it means you are not sick anymore.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps. Thank you. That's very helpful to me. I have added another example about the lab in response to your concern. So here, the research work does *end* with the discovery of the solution. *Not* researching anymore.

Comment: I would really use *"pendant"* instead of *"depuis"* for your point (2). And I've changed my mind: *"Après avoir été à Paris **pendant** deux jours, je rencontre Tom."* doesn't *necessarily* mean you are not in Paris anymore, but it's ambiguous. And if you want to keep the infinitive, *"Après avoir passé deux jours à Paris, je rencontre Tom."* sounds more idiomatic, but is still ambiguous about you are still in Paris when you meet Tom, or not. Note that turning things over in my head starts to make me doubt about what is correct or not.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps. Turning things over in your head makes you doubt what's correct! How well I know what that means. Your last bit was very helpful again. Finally, would this be OK: *Je passe deux jours à Paris lorsque je rencontre Tom*. If you say yes, then I will have what I need, i.e. a historical present (*passe*) turning into a past infinitive (*avoir passé*).

Comment: What sounds strange with that sentence is that you didn't know you were going to meet Tom after two days, until you actually meet him, so precising *deux jours* sounds like you had planned to stay two days and you meet him during this period. *"Je passe du temps à Paris lorsque, après deux jours, je rencontre Tom."* is more what you need. Or: *"Je suis à Paris depuis deux jours lorsque je rencontre Tom"*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps. I totally get what's wrong with *passe deux jours*. All told, I at least have *passe du temps* and *suis...depuis deux jours* correlating with *avoir passé deux jours*, which is good enough for me. Thank you again for your fine-tuned guidance.

Comment: Both sentences are right in English and French for purposes of ***narration*** using the present tense like that. That is exactly how the narrative present is used. But I do not understand what is meant by turning it into an infinitive. I do not understand what you mean by: a sentence that embeds an infinitive.

Comment: If your task doesn’t require using «avoir», maybe you could expand the possibilities by exploring verbs that use “être” in the passé composé  (e.g.: «J’arrive à Paris et (deux jours plus tard/après) je rencontre Tom (deux jours plus tard/après).» …. «Deux jours après être arrivé/e à Paris, je rencontre Tom»). (I’ll leave the discussion of whether this example is idiomatic (or even grammatically correct) to someone else)

Comment: @Catomic - shouldn't "I have been working on the project for two years when I find the solution." be "I have been working on the project for two years when I *found* the solution." ?

Comment: @Frank. That would be normal narration (as opposed to historic present): "I *had* been working on the project for two years when I *found* the solution."

Comment: @Catomic - ok - yeah you are right. See my other comments about the present throughout in your second example - I think it is completely ok (I like it actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present tense for narration is a little special there are a few quirks you should know.

1st question:

> Je suis à Paris depuis deux jours lorsque je rencontre Tom.

That's correct. You meet Tom in Paris.

> Je travaille sur le projet depuis deux ans lorsque je trouve la solution.

A bit weird, because finding the solution often implies you stop working on the project. Your second option is much better.

2nd question:

> *Après avoir été à Paris depuis deux jours, je rencontre Tom.*

This one sounds a little weird. I'm not 100% sure it's not correct, but I wouldn't use it. I'd say the tenses are not consistent with what you mean. It's either :

> Après avoir été à Paris **pendant** deux jours, je rencontre Tom à Londres

You're back from Paris. *J'ai été* translates well with "I went", it's over, you're back. Or:

> Après avoir **passé** deux jours à Paris, je rencontre Tom

Probably in Paris. You could also mean in a different place, but with no indication we'll understand you met him in Paris.

> Après avoir travaillé sur le projet depuis deux ans, je trouve la solution.

Perfectly good sentence. It doesn't mean you found the solution *after* you stopped working on your project, rather that the sum of two years of efforts lead you to finding the solution.

---

About your comment, "*Je passe deux jours à Paris lorsque je rencontre Tom*" means you're in the middle of spending two days in Paris when you meet him. You could be there for the weekend and meet him on Saturday night. *Lorsque* plays an important role here.

Kind of like when you say "*Je mange*", it means "*I'm eating*", so "*Je passe deux jours à Paris*" means "*I'm (in the middle of) spending two days in Paris*" (when you're telling a story, not when you say "*Je mange tard le week-end*". That's related to the values of the present tense (see [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicatif_pr%C3%A9sent_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Les_valeurs_de_pr.C3.A9sent))

---

Bonus: (I figured you'd like some sample narration in present tense. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.)

> Songeur, le chien **rentre** dans sa niche. Après *avoir croisé* précautionneusement ses pattes avant, il **pose** délicatement son menton dessus et **se trouve** bientôt plongé dans un abîme de réflexions. Il n’*a pas aperçu* le chat de toute la matinée. Au début, ça ne l’*a pas gêné* outre mesure, il *se sentait* même exceptionnellement guilleret, mais insensiblement un malaise l’*a gagné*. Il **essaie** de se rappeler si une absence aussi prolongée *s’est déjà produite*. Autour de la niche, les feuilles **bruissent** mais rien ne **signale** à son oreille fine la démarche d’un félin domestique. Il *faudra* voir en fin d’après-midi, quand le contenu de sa gamelle *sera changé*. Arrivé à ce point de ses réflexions, il **s’endort**.

([Source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_de_narration#Pr.C3.A9sent))

Comment: I'm glad we agree on almost every point. I'm just not sure *"avoir été"* *necessarily* means it's over, and it could be confusing because we often say "avoir été" instead of "être allé". But this point gives me headache.

Comment: Fantastic! I'll have to let this sink into my mind over a few days. I may return with questions. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Yeah, me too. I can't tell for sure if it's correct or not. (But it sounds weird so I wouldn't say it anyway). But to me, using "*après que*" necessarily means the following action is over. If the action is "spending two days" it doesn't mean you can't spend a third, but if it's "*being is Paris*" you're probably not there anymore. By the way if you agree feel free to upvote :)

Comment: "Je travaille sur le projet depuis deux ans lorsque je trouve la solution." sounds really good to me. It's just a style, all in the present tense. It could totally be written by a novelist, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

> Après deux jours passés à Paris, je rencontre Tom.

Another more simple form:

> Après deux jours à Paris, je rencontre Tom.

Comment: Thank you. I realize your sentences sound better. But I am trying to clarify a grammatical issue for my own understanding. I need an infinitive embedded in a present tense main clause.

Comment: it seems difficult to embed infinitive form in present clause

Comment: Thank you. Please see if the new example about a research project removes this particular difficulty. If it does, please see if the new sentences in both 1 and 2 are (grammatically) OK.

Comment: @Catomic I don't see anything wrong with "*Après avoir passé deux jours à Paris, je rencontre Tom*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat. Thanks. And you'd also be OK with *Je passe deux jours à Paris lorsque je rencontre Tom*?  And think they are equivalent?

Comment: @Catomic I'm writing an answer atm.

Answer (score 1):

« Je suis ici depuis deux jours » may seem mystifying to English-speaking persons, as much as “I have been here (for) two days.” for francophones: just two approaches of the same idea, how interesting.

In fact, the present perfect is not perfect at all, that is to say the “action” of the verb is not yet terminated (non perfecta est): I'm still here. So the English-speaking locutor “stretches” the past tense up to the present, the action being still performed. In French, the présent or the imparfait (i.e.: non perfect, non definitely performed, not yet ended) is somewhat stretched into the past. Result is the same, technics are different, vive la diversité !

Now, **nobody** will say: « Je suis à Paris depuis deux jours lorsque je rencontre Tom. », except in some (rare?) cases of présent de narration. But are perfectly French: « J'habite à Paris depuis deux ans », or: « J'habitais en Île-de-France depuis deux ans lorsque je rencontrai Tom » (please, not: « rencontra » which is for *il* or *elle*, not *je*), or « J'étais à peine arrivé à Paris depuis deux jours que je rencontre Tom ».

Pas forcément évident, mais moins difficile que ça en a l'air …     ;–)

Answer (score 0):

I would place "lorsque" instead of "quand" in this sentence.

> J'étais à Paris depuis deux jours lorsque je rencontra Tom

or

> J'étais à Paris depuis deux jours lorsque j'ai rencontré Tom

Comment: I think it's clear that the OP wants to use present tense for narration.

Comment: *Je rencontra* is not a form that exist in modern French conjugation.

Answer (score -4):

Both sentences in French sounds wrong to me. 
I'd rather say

> J'étais à Paris depuis deux jours quand je rencontra Tom.

or

> Après avoir été à Paris pendant deux jours, je rencontra Tom.

Comment: je rencontra Tom is wrong!