# Is there a greater suggestion of continuance in historic present than in imperfect?

Tags: temps-grammatical, imparfait

This question is on these two sentences.

The first one is from chapter 6 of La porte étroite by André Gide.

> Miss Ashburton, dont la santé depuis quelques mois **déclinait**, mourut quatre jours avant Noël.

The second one is from this [earlier post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24360/how-to-turn-je-suis-%C3%A0-paris-depuis-deux-into-an-infinitive).

> Je **travaille** sur le projet depuis deux ans lorsque je trouve la solution

This sentence is meant to be in the historic present narration.  (If you need concrete context, imagine the opening of a movie with voice-over narration.  The voice belongs to a character who is in a coma, to whom everything is the present. He recounts to you the events leading to his accident, starting:  "I have been working on the project for two years when I find the solution. Everyone is there in the lab to congratulate me. No one notices the [warning signs]. . .")

The second sentence was called into question (thought "a little weird") in the earlier post because (insofar as I can understand it) a solution suggests end of work while *travaille* suggests its continuance.  I add that there was also a dissenting voice, which found the sentence just fine.

**QUESTION**

Is the Gide sentence "weird" to a different (i.e. lesser) degree?

**BACKGROUND**

Please note that I am not asking whether the second sentence is or is not weird.  It's enough for me that it can *sound* weird to some ear at some time.

What I ask is whether this weirdness is exacerbated by *travaille* being in the (historic) present while *déclinait*, in the imperfect, is less weird or not weird at all.

You will note that death would end the decline as effectively as a solution might research work.

Obviously if you thought both sounded just fine, you might not have much to say about the relative degrees of weirdness.

This [other post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24352/how-to-turn-imparfait-into-infinitif-when-the-imparfait-denotes-a-duration-termi) is on the Gide sentence, but is not highly relevant to this post.

Comment: "a solution suggests end of work while travaille suggests its continuance." Yes. But we don’t know the solution of what it’s about… He may have found a solution to a part of the project, so this part ended but the whole project is still continuing.

Comment: I find it confusing that you are referring to some previous post as if we are supposed to remember it. Or, you are asking us to go and see it and come back here. I don't see how the two sentences are comparable at all. Perhaps you might enlighten me.

Comment: @Lambie. I made the question self-standing. No need to visit the earlier post. The question is simply *if* you saw a problem in the second sentence whether you found it in the first sentence as well. If someone does not see a problem in the second, the question may not make any sense, which would be natural.

Comment: @Catomic, but one is in the narrative present and the other is not using that  at all. There is no relationship between the imperfect declinait and travaille that I can suss out at all. If Gide's had been in the same form, then it would have been: Miss Ashburton, dont la santé depuis quelques mois décline, meurt quatre jours avant Noël.

Comment: I like "Miss Ashburton, dont la santé depuis quelques mois décline, meurt quatre jours avant Noël." very much :-)

Comment: @Lambie. Right; we're not saying they are the same. Only asking whether *imperfect* has the same problem *present* does or might. In short, you understand the question as well as anyone else and, I believe, even came down on one side.

Comment: @Catomic - the imperfect definitely does not have the same potential issue as the present - but IMHO simply because that imperfect is much more common narrative style. Also note that now we have *two* things going on: the present tense, but also Teleporting Goat's issue about _lorsque_ not jibing with _depuis deux ans_. IMHO, both are "undecided" at this point. I feel they are just stylistic variations personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was writing about the Gide sentence explaining why it makes sense, but I realize it's not the point, the real problem is with the second one.

It feels weird of the combo "*deux ans*" + "*lorsque*". The suddennes of "*lorsque*" doesn't match very well with the long duration of two years. It's like saying "I was doing something for 2 years then **suddenly** I found a solution".

You can say :

> Je **mange** mon sandwich sans faire attention aux gens autour de moi lorsqu'un inconnu vient m'approcher.

The tenses are the same, it also uses *lorsque*, but the implication are different. Eating a sandwich is a somewhat short action, it makes sense to be interrupted.

Also, "*Je travaille sur un projet depuis deux ans*" doesn't sound like narration present, it sounds like general truth present, just like saying "*je travaille dans l'immobilier*". And you cannot use "*lorsque*" in a sentence using general truth present, it just doesn't make sense.

In your sentence, I understand that finding the solution marked the end of the project, that's an important component. Using "*depuis*" with present means you're still doing the action (*pendant* often means it's over, but not necessarily). You can use present for narration but still use past for stuff that already happened at the time of the story.

Narration present is more about describing short actions. You can describe long actions (more than a day I mean), but it sounds weird to interrupt them with a short sentence.

You could say :

> Je travaille sur ce projet pendant 2 ans. Un jour, je trouve la solution.

or

> Je commence à travailler sur ce projet. Deux ans plus tard/Après deux ans, je trouve la solution.

(If those two sentences raise more questions, please ask them in comment as they come.)

Comment: Intéressant. On pourrait aussi utiliser _quand_ plutôt que _lorsque_. Mais _lorsque_ ne me choque pas. Le problème de perception serait le même avec _quand_ de toute façon. Il faudrait voir si _quand_ et _lorsque_ sont proscrits ici, ou non, ou si c'est une déviance/dérive.

Comment: Aussi, _lorsque_ a/a eu d’autres usages. J’ai trouvé “_Ils n’auront pas la maison avant dix ans, lorsque je devrais crever de faim entre les quatre murs_” ( dans Zola, Au Bonheurs des Dames) dans le Grevisse. Ces autres usages pourraient contribuer a affaiblir l’implication de simultanéité dans le mot _lorsque_.

Comment: Questions for Teleporting Goat would be: 1. Does changing the second sentence to *depuis deux semaines* or *jours* make it more acceptable then? 2. Does changing *lorsque* to *quand* change anything (per @Frank's observation)? Thanks.

Comment: Like you said in an another comment, it's difficult to say why I don't like the expression. 2. *Quand* doesn't change much IMO. The problem is the same with simultaneity and suddenness, you're comparing a very long action with a short one, and that supposedly ends the first one. It's really the combination of all this stuff that makes it weird. The "*depuis*" also bothers me, notice I used "*pendant*" in my alternative solutions. (It brings back to the part about general truth present.) I have more stuff to say about that so I'll edit my answer.

Comment: And 1., It's a little less weird but I'd still say this differently. I'm sorry I can't really give more consistent explanation ^^ Also, to answer Frank,*lorsque* doesn't *always* imply suddenness, it depends on the context, but finding example doesn't change that it does in this sentence.

Comment: @Catomic This is really messing with my head. I think half of the problem is the present narration almost always sounds closer to spoken language, and using "*lorsque*" in the middle of the sentence like this, with no punctuation does exactly the opposite. Even with another word, the sentence doesn't sound like spoken French at all (even good spoken French). The sample with the dog I gave in the other answer is much closer to the idea I have of narration present. IMO it's a style much more than a tense you can use for anything and everything. I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks again, Teleporting Goat. I suggest you give it a rest for now. There's plenty of material here for me to try to absorb.

Comment: The more I think about it, the less I am convinced that _lorsque_ is not perfectly valid here :-) This morning I take the sentence to mean: "*at the point where I had worked on that project, suddenly, I found the solution*" and, and Teleporting Goat's arguments seem to all vanish :-)

Comment: @Frank "*had worked*" and "*found*" are different tenses (both past tenses). (One of) the problem(s) is using present tense, and using it *twice*.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - I know - I was not attempting to render the French present, but to show that maybe we could see all the past effort on the project as 1 event, when the solution is found. "_I work on the project for two years, and at that point, I find the solution". The suddenness you feel in _lorsque_ gets back-propagated in a sense.

Comment: But suddenness IMHO is not quite the right way to understand _lorsque_. There are plenty of examples along the line of: _lorsqu'il pleut, les oiseaux se taisent_.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that yes, in the second sentence, the present tense *travaille*, was chosen for its stylistic impact, bringing a sense of immediacy to the narration. So yes, that *travaille* would be the key to making this sentence interesting (it is, IMHO, a good, pleasant style).

I think "weird" is not the right word here. It's just different styles, the second one probably being more "modern" (not implying common) than Gide's style. My feeling is that writers before the fifties probably would not have considered using this present tense style (I could be wrong).

Comment: I wanted to know why the sentence might not sit well with someone, but it is also valuable to know that it is "good, pleasant style" to someone else. Thanks.

Comment: @Catomic - yes - I saw the details of your question. It's interesting that Teleporting Goat had a completely different reason for being "surprised". I can understand his feeling, but it is not as significant for me. I think the style is definitely distinctive. Did you see my 2 comments in French below Teleporting Goat's answer? I'm still trying to dig into this _lorsque_.

Comment: @Catomic - also note that Teleporting Goat's main premise is that _lorsque_ necessarily implies suddenness - which I am disputing. I do not know for sure if _lorsque_ is supposed to inevitably imply suddenness and I'm looking for examples where it doesn't. I found one example where _lorsque_ was used with another meaning. Also, I have data (googe ngrams) showing that lorsque is less common than _quand_.

Comment: @Catomic - the dictionary from the French Academy gives the following definition for _lorsque_: "Quand, au moment où. J'en jugerai lorsque je serai mieux informé. Lorsqu'il est arrivé, je sortais. Lorsqu'il pleut, les oiseaux se taisent." Note how it seems like it implies simultaneity more than suddenness, esp. in "Lorsqu'il pleut, les oiseaux se taisent." - Teleporting Goat might be after _simultaneity_ rather than _suddenness_.

Comment: Yes I saw your comments to Teleporting Goat. It's often difficult to bring out why one doesn't like some expression. I think it's a subtle thing with him too.

Comment: Yeap - this thread touches upon subtleties beyond simple grammatical correctness, and there might not necessarily be a single answer :-)